# ASP.NET use of Session ID

Tags: webforms

I'm working with an old ASP.NET application which has lots of lousy code.

I have been mostly a winform developer and my knowledge of webforms is still limited.

However looking at code the way the developer tried to pass information to other pages sound invalid to me.

Here is a typical way he passes info from one page to other page:

```
Response.Redirect("ABC.aspx?SessionID=08F7DCF3D6984EC984F6580A4EC7E9C2&CID=" _
                    & e.Item.Cells(iColClientID).Text & "", True)
```

Then on other pages he uses Request.QueryString to get the data back:

```
Request.QueryString
```

My question is why in the world he needs to also pass a Hardcoded `SessionID=08F7DCF3D6984EC984F6580A4EC7E9C2` in the query string.

Web.config shows :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
```

So if session is using cookies why send session id?

To me code is written by an amature developer. Please provide your feedback.

Comment: What does the `SessionID` actually do in ABC.aspx??

Comment: Have you noticed what he is doing with the SessionID after reading from query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless he uses the `SessionID` parameter for something else -some other obscure logic in there that relies on it being present in the QueryString-, there's no reason to put a `SessionID` in the query string at all. With or without cookies enabled how to get the `SessionID` should be transparent to you and it suffices to do:

```
var sessionID = Session.SessionID;
```

Some relevant documentation from MSDN regarding cookieless sessions (which **is not** the case here according to the Web.config you showed):

> ASP.NET maintains cookieless session state by automatically inserting
>   a unique session ID into the page's URL. For example, the following
>   URL has been modified by ASP.NET to include the unique session ID
>   lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55:
>   http://www.example.com/(S(lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55))/orderform.aspx
>   When ASP.NET sends a page to the browser, it modifies any links in the
>   page that use an application-relative path by embedding a session ID
>   value in the links. (Links with absolute paths are not modified.)
>   Session state is maintained as long as the user clicks links that have
>   been modified in this manner. However, if the client rewrites a URL
>   that is supplied by the application, ASP.NET may not be able to
>   resolve the session ID and associate the request with an existing
>   session. In that case, a new session is started for the request.

Comment: Very Good. Since we can so easily access sessionID object using   var sessionID = Session.SessionID;

Then what's the point of sending a hardcoded number as a session id to Response.Redirect

Comment: What I mean is, since session ID is automatically generated, in the second form , If we want to get data using from the session, do we need to use the Request.QueryString method at all? All of the information in the 1st page can be stored in the session object. I appreciate if you can explian any drawbacks with this method.

Comment: @SNash no, no need to put the SessionID in the QuetyString within the same application. Some people use techniques like this (appending a SessionID to the query string) to transfer control over to a different applications that use this `SessionID` to validate something. Again, this doesn't seem to be your case.